# Merge script between 2 tables and not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I have a code that i was still wondering why it should not work, I want to merge these two tables and look at the code below and tables with error generated. Please the tables are just extracted, and have more rows than pasted below. Just sample

```
MERGE INTO [server1].[DATABASE].[dbo].[MD_ToolsMaintDate] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * from  [server2].[DATABASE].[dbo].[MD_ToolsMaintDate])    AS SOURCE 

   ON TARGET.MaintDate = SOURCE.MaintDate 
     AND  Target.MDToolID  = Source.MDToolID
   AND Target.SerialID = Source.SerialID

  WHEN MATCHED AND
    (

      OR Target.ComponentID   <> Source.ComponentID
      OR Target.Notes        <> Source.Notes 
    )        

 THEN 
 UPDATE SET 

 , TARGET.ComponentID = SOURCE.ComponentID  
 , TARGET.Notes = SOURCE.Notes 

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT  ( SerialID,MDToolID,MaintDate,ComponentID,Notes)
    VALUES ( SOURCE.SerialID, SOURCE.MDToolID, SOURCE.MaintDate,SOURCE.ComponentID, SOURCE.Notes);

         SELECT * FROM [server1].[DATABASE].[dbo].[MD_ToolsMaintDate]
```

> ERROR :  The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

```
   -----server 1 table :

  MaintenanceID SerialID    MDToolID    MaintDate   ComponentID     Notes

218       8          4     2016-05-26 01:00:00.0000000      NULL     pivot 
219      9           4     2016-08-06 21:15:00.0000000      NULL             
220      130         4     2016-08-09 00:00:00.0000000      NULL                  NULL        

    -----server 2 table :

MaintenanceID SerialID  MDToolID    MaintDate     ComponentID          Notes
45            130        4  2016-02-09 00:00:00.0000000  NULL          CHECK ME
49            131        5  2016-02-09 00:00:00.0000000  NULL          CHECK ME
```

Any correction and way to do this will be appreciated. The Mainatance ID on both tables can never remain the same because the two tables are even in different location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not looks well. Typically, youre updating other columns, than used in join (declaring source and target objects). At this case, you are updating same columns, as used in merge join. Other problem: merge join condition says, that values must be the same. Then when values are the same ("when matched.."), you are additionally saying that values, that used in merge join (must match), must does not match. Remaining part also is not clear. 
Please read books online to clear-out how merge must be implemented:
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx](http://merge%20books%20online)

---

```
MERGE INTO [server1].[DATABASE].[dbo].[MD_ToolsMaintDate] WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS TARGET 
USING
(
    SELECT 
         [SerialID]
        ,[MDToolID]
        ,[MaintDate]
        ,[ComponentID]
        ,[Notes]
    FROM  
        [server2].[DATABASE].[dbo].[MD_ToolsMaintDate]
)    AS SOURCE 
(
         [SerialID]
        ,[MDToolID]
        ,[MaintDate]
        ,[ComponentID]
        ,[Notes]
)
ON 
        TARGET.[MaintDate]  = SOURCE.[MaintDate]
    AND TARGET.[MDToolID]   = SOURCE.[MDToolID]
    AND TARGET.[SerialID]   = SOURCE.[SerialID]
WHEN MATCHED AND
(
        TARGET.[ComponentID]    <> SOURCE.[ComponentID]
    OR  TARGET.[Notes]          <> SOURCE.[Notes] 
)
THEN UPDATE 
    SET 
         TARGET.[ComponentID]   = SOURCE.[ComponentID]
        ,TARGET.[Notes]         = SOURCE.[Notes] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT  
    ( 
         [SerialID]
        ,[MDToolID]
        ,[MaintDate]
        ,[ComponentID]
        ,[Notes]
    )
    VALUES
    (
         SOURCE.[SerialID]
        ,SOURCE.[MDToolID]
        ,SOURCE.[MaintDate]
        ,SOURCE.[ComponentID]
        ,SOURCE.[Notes]
    );
```

Comment: I have edited it. It is just the duplicate column name.

Comment: I updated my first post with new query. Can you try it?

Comment: Hi Juozas, I have tested the script and it says 0 rows affected. Thanks

Comment: Is it planned result by data you have on server1, server2?

Comment: no. It will depend on the input at anytime and the two servers are in different location. I think the script is fine, but still not working. I have linked both server and not sure, why it is not making any change. Any other method to use without merge. The problem with update or union all, is that it will keep putting duplicate anytime the script run, so if any other method will work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Juozas Is possible to use union all since there is no need for sorting rows or column, but just to avoid duplicate

Comment: Yes, UNION eliminates all duplicates between recordset A and B. Other way is to use UNION ALL, but group final result by all columns:
https://gist.github.com/runnerlt/142510f2ffcaa7019ccb88f26d9a126d

Comment: The script merge is working now. I found out that the Linked server in genaral tab I set up was using OLE DB and I changed it to SQL Server and in the security tab I used Be made without using a security context, i changed it to the fourth option which is using Be made using this security context and I provided the SQL server login.  The union and union all still are limited though. Thanks for the script.

Answer (score 1):

SAMPLE QUERY:-

```
<----- **USING MERGE** ----->

merge into [#server1] as t1
using(select * from [#server2]) as t2
on t1.[maintenanceid]=t2.[maintenanceid]
when matched then
update set 
t1.[serialid]=[t2.serialid],
t1.[mdtoolid]=[t2.mdtoolid],
t1.[maindate]=t2.[maindate],
t1.[componentid]=t2.[componentid],
t1.[note]=t2.[note]
when not matched then
insert values(t2.[maintenanceid],t2.[serialid],t2.[mdtoolid],t2.[maindate],t2.[componentid],t2.[note]);
```

Comment: This will only work if the Maintanance is not unique, there Mainance ID will always be different, and  will can not use it as measure.May be I can use the MaintDate, SerialID and MDToolId for that because that mght be solution. I will try this code using these there column and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vinoth, As I said, the maintenanceid is not usable because an application control it and it would not allow insert values in that row. The problem is that maintenanceid is different at both servers, even if it is inserted without maintenanceid , it will keep duplicating values which is not what I wanted.